# Problema com programa que imprime três numeros de forma crescente

Tags: c, c++, lógica

Estou com problema em criar as estruturas de decisão em um programa que lê 3 números e os imprime de forma crescente. O meu código que está dando errado é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int A, B, C;

    scanf("%d %d %d" ,&A, &B, &C);

    if(A<B<C)
    {
       printf("%d %d %d" ,A, B, C);
    }      
      else
    {
        printf("%d %d %d", C, B, A);

        if(B<A<C)
        {
            printf("%d %d %d", B, C, A);
        }
    }

return 0;

}
```

O que devo fazer para testar todas as possibilidades?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta pode não ser a melhor forma de fazer isto mas como acho que você está aprendendo não vou tentar mexer muito na sua lógica. Vou resolver dois problemas existentes nele.

O primeiro é que você não pode fazer uma comparação complexa. O computador funciona como nosso cérebro, ele faz uma operação de cada vez. Ele não pode comprar se 3 números um é menor que o outro. Você só pode comparar dois números de cada vez. Você faz uma comparação e depois faz outra comparação e depois faz uma outra que junta as duas. Essa operação que vai juntar as duas é o "E lógico", ou seja ambas operações devem ser verdadeiras para tudo ser verdadeiro. Em C o operador responsável por isto é o `&&`.

O segundo problema é que você não verificou todas as possibilidades de ordem.

Existe um outro problema que o código está mal organizado talvez por você desconhecer o `else if` que executa se a condição anterior for falsa. Mas ela já verifica uma outra condição. Dá para fazer sem o `else if`, basta eliminar todos os `else`s e tornar os `if`s independentes. Ainda assim tem como fazer de outro jeito e mais otimizado (só de reordenar a sequência de cada condição já otimizaria um pouco), mas não vou complicar para você. Acho que já estou introduzindo vários conceitos novos.

Ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int A, B, C;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &A, &B, &C);
    if (A < B && B < C) printf("%d %d %d", A, B, C);
    else if (C < B && B < A) printf("%d %d %d", C, B, A);
    else if (B < A && A < C) printf("%d %d %d", B, C, A);
    else if (A < C && C < B) printf("%d %d %d", A, C, B);
    else if (B < A && A < C) printf("%d %d %d", B, A, C);
    else if (C < A && A < B) printf("%d %d %d", C, A, B);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/upfZCr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xonsaalb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SortThree2.c).

Answer (score 3):

Há um problema na lógica, pois como você mesmo disse, você não está cobrindo todas as possibilidades. Além disso há um problema de semântica em:

```
if(a<b<c)
{
    //seu código
}
```

Não é possível fazer essa comparação direto, a comparação deve ser feita dois a dois, desse jeito:

```
if((a<b) && (b<c)) // && significa /\ (o "e" em lógica)
{
    //seu código
}
```

Uma solução para o seu problema é criar um vetor de elementos, ordená-lo e depois imprimir seus elementos.Dessa forma, para um vetor de n elementos o códiog é o seguinte:

```
void ordenavetor(int vet[], int n)
{
    int i,j,aux;

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(vet[i]>vet[j])
            {
                aux = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[j];
                vet[j] = aux;
            }
        }
}
```

Depois, crie um laço **for** para imprimir os elementos do vetor:

```
void imprimeVetor(int vet[],int n)
{   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      printf("%d ", vet[i]);
}
```

Essa é apenas uma das soluções,pois existem diversos outros algoritmos que realizam a mesma tarefa de maneira mais rápida.

Answer (score 1):

Este codigo faz uma coisa engracada.

```
if (A < B < C) /* ... */;
```

Primeiro ele compara `A` e `B` obtendo `0` ou `1`; depois compara esse valor com `C`

```
 if ((A < B) < C) /* ... */;
 if (0 < C) /* ... */;
 if (1 < C) /* ... */;
```